# Cannot change value of a variable in c++

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to choose between two integer numbers, it generate a random number and if it's even chose one and if it's odd choose the other integer. I have detected that the problem don't assign the value to variable aux, it can distinguish between even and odd functions, it returns the initial value of aux. Thanks so much!

```
#include "randomize.h"

//FUNCTION randoripair: choose between two numbers
int randoripair(int k, int a, int b){
    int aux,i,j;

    aux=randomize(k,0,1000);
    if(aux%2==0){
        aux = a;
    }else{
        aux=b;
    }  
   return aux;
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: How do you call randoripair() ?

Comment: `aux` doesn't even have an initial value. I suspect that you're misinterpreting some of your symptoms.

Comment: BTW, a shorter version is `return randomize(k, 0, 1000) % 2 == 0 ? a : b;`.

Comment: "I have detected that the problem don't assign the value to variable aux" please describe how you detected that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that the error is somewhere else in the code. Your code snippet seems correct. Are you sure, that `randomize` returns a value? How is it defined? Did you debug the code?

Comment: Try compiling your program with all warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` on gcc) and make sure there are no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be okay. There might be a problem on a different point in this code. 
 
1) Check if `randomize(k, 0, 1000);` returns a valid value. Simply add a `std::cout<<"Random: "<<aux<<std::endl;` after `aux=randomize(k,0,1000);`. 
2) Please provide your call to this function. Maybe your function call is not correct.

Comment: I did it, it return the random value of aux. I paste randomize's code here: https://pastebin.com/tnCkZ4QA